# jQuery not detecting link on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is a rails 4.2 project using HAML

I'm looking to have a clickable image to trigger some functionality on click. I need to have accessible the image source.

**rails view**

```
- @gallery.pictures.each do |picture|
  = link_to image_tag(picture.image.url, class: 'thumb'), "#", class: "gallery_image"
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
  $('.gallery_image').on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('This is a clickable image')

    // do something
  })
```

---

Right now, it works fine as a link. It redirects to, well... "#", but the console never shows `this is a clickable image`.

I know the javascript is accessed because if I add a typo, Google Chrome console immediately yells.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Wrap your jQuery into a DOM ready function
- Use the `event` argument
- Assign the click to your child `.thumb`

```
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  $('.gallery_image').on('click', '.thumb', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('This is a clickable image');

    // do something
  });

  // other DOM dependent code here

});
```